# Trouble when ugrading PHP & Apache

Tags: php, apache, wamp

Today, I have on my Windows 8.1 computer (64bit), Wampserver 2.4, php 5.4.12, and apache 2.4.4 . Because of my student project, i have to upgrade my php version to 5.5.10. For this, I used this tutorial : http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,113423,113435#msg-113435

I did every line in this tutorial, but, when i tried to switch php version in wampServer, i got this message :

> this php version doesn't seem to be compatible with your actual apache version

So, i installed a VC11 (2.4.9) apache version, but this time, when i switched my apache version, i got this very intersting message :

> this Apache version doesn't seem to be compatible with your actual PHP version

This message almost killed me... so i checked in httpd.conf, (i compared it to my old apache version) but nothing more happened...

If someone can help me find out the solution, or give me a tutorial for my case.. I'll be very greatfull.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you installed the 64bit version of WAMPServer. That means you installed a 64bit Apache/PHP/MySQL.

When you added php version to 5.5.10 did you check that it was a 64bit version? It will need to be!